# Understand the English paragraph on association rule.

Tags: statistics, computer-science, mathematical-physics, statistical-inference, machine-learning

I am currently studying Association Rule Pattern Mining. I am reading the explanation on wikipedia about it. Somehow, I feel like I have a problem in understanding the paragraph below.

Can somebody explain this in plain English, I believe the explanation below is written easy enough, but I can't think of "how 1,000,000,000,000" rules are calculated and why we are expected to find rules like "50,000,000,000".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule is made of $3$ items, there are $10,000 = 10^4$ items so there are $(10^4)^3 = 10^{12} = 1,000,000,000,000$ rules. Significance is $0.05$ so you get $0.05 \cdot 10^{12} = 50,000,000,000$.

I don't actually know anything about associations, but if I didn't answer your question, you should revise it.

Comment: Any 2 items of the 3 items can be in the left-side and any 1 item can be in the right-side. It seems like you have answered my question. I am just wondering how you have meant your expression$(10^4)^3$?

Comment: $(10^4)^3 = 10^4 \cdot 10^4 \cdot 10^4 = 10^{4+4+4}$. It's a [basic rule of exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties).

Comment: What does that have your expression $(10^4)^3$ with 2 items in the left-side and 1 item in the right-side? can you please give me a further explanation for it?

Comment: @user122358, two items on the left and one item on the right, for example "$a, b \to c$", simply means three slots for items. It might be reasonable, in some context, to consider "$a, b \to c$" to be the same as "$b, a \to c$", or for $a, b \to a$ to be invalid, but the paragraph doesn't - it would otherwise get a lower number of rules. Now, if you have three slots and can put one of $10^4$ items in each, you end up with $(10^4)^3$ rules. Try it out with 3 slots and 2 items, to get 8 rules.